# Managing 301 redirects in a wordpress migration

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

My understanding of 301:

URL forwarding provided by most hosting companies is often 302 directing and does not inform the search engine that the site has actually moved.

The 301 redirects need to occur in the htaccess file located on the old domain hosting account.

My client believes the following will work but the logic does not make sense to me. Please let me know if it is correct.

Point the old domain name to the new domain name dropping the old hosting. Then use a 301 redirect wordpress plugin to handle the redirects. 
So essentially trying to visit old-site.com/blog would send you to new-site.com and the 301 redirect module would send you to /blog if that's what you had tried to visit on the old site.

Is this possible? To me I would think you would need to make a redirect of /blog -> new-site.com/blog and the redirect would need to be in the htaccess file of the old site.

Please tell me if I'm wrong. I very rarely handle any migrations but I thought I understood redirects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tl;dr: Talk the client out of their idea. Do the redirect in .htaccess

What your client is suggesting is certainly doable. However, doable != advisable..

That said, it would be most efficient to host both the old site and new site on the same server, and then put the redirect into either the .htaccess or better yet the actual vhost config (if allowed by the new host) on the new server.

If that is not an option (new host wont allow it, or some similar reason) then yes, better to just do the redirect in .htaccess on the old site.  Not only to address the possible SEO concerns regarding 301 vs 302, but also because it is more flexible.  The only real downside to your approach vs the clients suggestion is the continued billing for the old webhosting. If you can mitigate that by moving the hosting for both to the same place, great, if not, keep both hosting accounts despite the cost.

Comment: They are moving from one real estate hosting company to another. So one out dated cms to a multi site wordpress site.

I guess I just dont understand how if you visit old-site.com/blog/some post and it is just pointed to new-site.com, that new-site.com will know your intention was to visit new-site.com/blog/some-post/

Comment: Still no reason to keep the old hosting if the redirect can be done on the new hosting.

Comment: The sites are different servers, different domain names. They simply want to use the "point this domain name to a different site" option that is on the domain name control panel. 

Then they believe that they can do redirects and say, if the intention was to visit old-site.com/blog redirect to new-site.com/blog/

If that were the case, couldn't I start entering redirects telling people trying to go to google to go to my site instead?

Comment: No, because you cannot redirect google.com. They can redirect their own site. Now, the issue with redirection via their domain registrar possibly using 302 instead of 301 is still a valid concern with regards to SEO.  Just because the client can do what they are suggesting, doesnt make it a great idea.

Comment: Regarding different servers... why keep it that way? Why not use the same server for both domains? Will the new host not allow that?

Comment: I was just using google as an example... 

But they can't use the same servers, totally different companies using totally different servers. They want to get rid of the old hosting company entirely. 

And that was my thought that the service that the domain control panel is offering is a 302 redirect.

Comment: I edited my answer for clarity. Not quite following why they cant host both domains at the new host, but some hosts have weird policies. Either way, yes, the .htaccess is how they should do the redirect - and *not* via their registrar.

Comment: Thank you, the edited version makes more sense. I guess the confusion was with being able to host multiple domains per one account. I now understand how that would work completely, but I'm not sure if it's an option yet. Basically point domain to new hosting account, create a hosting account for the old domain and put the .htaccess into that folder. Then do all the rewrites within that .htaccess file. Seems like this is the most viable option provided their hosting will allow for it.